# How can I embed a googledrive folder on to my website without showing the owner name

Tags: google-drive-api, embed

I would like to embed a google drive folder onto my web site but do not want to show the owner name or the name. Is it possible?

Comment: can you accept my answer so we can close this?

Comment: No problem - thanks for this how do I accept your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to disable to do this as of now. There is no mention of this in Google Drive and this [SO thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21578/how-do-i-change-my-nickname-or-display-name-on-google-docs) suggests the same thing. I tried this on a sample site and it's always there - the name of the modifier.

Try to make your own implementation so you can modify it as you please.